# How to do FFMPEG video conversion with a bash Timeout wrapped in shell_exec() properly?

Tags: ffmpeg, timeout

I am converting videos server side (with Ubuntu and PHP) with:

```
$result = shell_exec("ffmpeg -i ".$filetmp." -vcodec h264 -filter:v fps=30 -acodec aac ".$filetmp.".mp4");
```

Some video conversions take several minutes and I need to stop them.

I have tried to give the ffmpeg command a timeout by using Ubuntu's [timeout](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/timeout.1.html) (in the following 30 seconds):

```
$result = shell_exec("timeout 30 ffmpeg -i ".$filetmp." -vcodec h264 -filter:v fps=30 -acodec aac ".$filetmp.".mp4 2>&1");
```

But the output contains *all the logs* from FFmpeg.

Even though the docs say:

> If  the  command times out, and --preserve-status is not set, then exit with status 124.

I tried adding `-loglevel quiet` to the FFmpeg command (in hope I only get the timeout output `124`) but then I get no logs.

On PHP side I try to catch the timeout with:

```
if ((int)$result == 124) { }
```

How to get only the code `124` from the timeout command - without the FFmpeg logs?

Besides, do I need `--kill-after=DURATION` for the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `;echo $?` in the end after `2>&1;`. Then the output is `124` from the timeout when reached.

Also for ffmpeg use `-loglevel quiet`.

```
$result = shell_exec("timeout -k 10 10 ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i ".$filetmp." -vcodec h264 -filter:v fps=30 -acodec aac ".$filetmp.".mp4 2>&1; echo $?");
```

Output:

> 124